# Android apply styles for different days

Tags: android, styles

How would you load up different styles for the layout based on different days of the week? In terms of styles I mean the overall color of the application.

Would you have to generate them dynamically and apply the style or is there a way easier way than this?

Comment: What did you tried so far? Show us your code, please.

Comment: you just need to create custom themes and apply them programmatically when checking the day of the week